# scroll to DOM id after Ajax load new content

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, scroll

I've wanted to dynamically display my portfolio content on the site - reloading whole page(header + content + footer) by ajax and now it works fine, but the site is pretty long and it shows after loading the bottom of it - how automatically scroll to portfolio section after load? I've tried using `.scrollTo()` but it doesn't work (maybe I'm putting it in the wrong line - please take a look at my code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".screen.fifth a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    /*
    if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
    if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link.
    */

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
      $('.screen.fifth .main_wrapper').html(data);
    }});

    //to change the browser URL to the given link location
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
      window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
    }
    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;
  });
});
```

Please help!

EDIT:

I've changed the link to this page to `<a href=".../project_one.php#project_tag">` and in chrome it works just fine, but in Firefox it behaves like I've described earlier :/

Comment: try `$('#portfolio_tag').focus()`

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 30},'slow');
}
```

It scrolls to an inputted id, so, if you want to scroll to `#portfolio_tag` then call:

```
goToByScroll('portfolio_tag');
```

once the AJAX call has been completed.

Comment: it doesn't work - still showing the bottom (footer) of the site :/ Tried with different tags in different places in code :/

Comment: so does it scroll to the bottom of the site? Got a link?

Comment: now I'm trying different thing: `<a href='...project_name.php#projects'>` You can take a look: http://ofcapl.vot.pl/tactica/ <- please click on portfolio link on the top right and then click on the first position ("Wawelska Tradycja 1949") - at first it shows proper section (for almost a 1sec, but then loads the footer and goes down :/ )

Comment: doesn't seem to be doing it for me... If I click the link, it loads the page at projects and just sits there. Though then after 1 second chrome pops up the 'do you wish to translate this page' bar and the footer appears. Is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: in chrome I have no problems - but try it in firefox

Comment: if you're using `#` anchors, you probably want to remove anything that moves the page on load. see where that gets you

Comment: I've deleted all js functions that was responsible for scrolling but with no effects :/ any clues?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like what's happening is that the page is jumping to the `#projects` anchor and then the page resizes when it's loaded.

So, if you put the following:

```
goToByScroll( window.location.hash.substring(1) );
```

after the code where the page resizes `($('.map').width(myWidth);)` in both the ready and resize functions, that should solve your problem